# Tensorflow 2.1 TPU v2 reduce memory usage with bfloat16

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, tpu

I have some issue with the TPUv2 regarding the memory usage.
I would like to do some experiment with some Large model but unfortunately the model does not fit the memory. I would like to use bfloat16 in order to save some memory but I have some issue when I call the model :

```
try:
    # TPU detection. No parameters necessary if TPU_NAME environment variable is
    # set: this is always the case on Kaggle.
    resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
    print('Running on TPU ', resolver.master())
except ValueError:
    resolver = None

if resolver:

  tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
  tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
  strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
else:
    # Default distribution strategy in Tensorflow. Works on CPU and single GPU.
    strategy = tf.distribute.get_strategy()


policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy('mixed_bfloat16')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)

with strategy.scope():

    model = CustomModel(TFXLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained("jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-large"),  num_classes=5)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
    optimizer = tf.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer, loss_scale='dynamic')

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=['mse'])
```

> InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in ()
>         3 with strategy.scope():
>         4 
>   ----> 5     model = CustomModel(TFXLMRobertaModel.from_pretrained("jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-large"),
>   num_classes=5)
>         6     optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-5)
>         7     optimizer = tf.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer(optimizer, loss_scale='dynamic')
>
> 13 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py
>   in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args,
>   **kwargs)
>       399             return load_pytorch_checkpoint_in_tf2_model(model, resolved_archive_file, allow_missing_keys=True)
>       400 
>   --> 401         model(model.dummy_inputs, training=False)  # build the network with dummy inputs
>       402 
>       403         assert os.path.isfile(resolved_archive_file), "Error retrieving file {}".format(resolved_archive_file)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
>       967               self._compute_dtype):
>   --> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
>       970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_roberta.py
>   in call(self, inputs, **kwargs)
>       222 
>       223         """
>   --> 224         outputs = self.roberta(inputs, **kwargs)
>       225         return outputs
>       226
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
>       967               self._compute_dtype):
>   --> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
>       970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.py
>   in call(self, inputs, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids,
>   head_mask, inputs_embeds, training)
>       567             # head_mask = tf.constant([0] * self.num_hidden_layers)
>       568 
>   --> 569         embedding_output = self.embeddings([input_ids, position_ids, token_type_ids, inputs_embeds], training=training)
>       570         encoder_outputs = self.encoder([embedding_output, extended_attention_mask, head_mask], training=training)
>       571
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
>       967               self._compute_dtype):
>   --> 968             outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>       969           self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)
>       970           self._set_mask_metadata(inputs, outputs, input_masks)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.py
>   in call(self, inputs, mode, training)
>       146         """
>       147         if mode == "embedding":
>   --> 148             return self._embedding(inputs, training=training)
>       149         elif mode == "linear":
>       150             return self._linear(inputs)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_roberta.py
>   in _embedding(self, inputs, training)
>        79                 position_ids = self.create_position_ids_from_inputs_embeds(inputs_embeds)
>        80 
>   ---> 81         return super()._embedding([input_ids, position_ids, token_type_ids, inputs_embeds], training=training)
>        82 
>        83
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_bert.py
>   in _embedding(self, inputs, training)
>       173 
>       174         embeddings = inputs_embeds + position_embeddings + token_type_embeddings
>   --> 175         embeddings = self.LayerNorm(embeddings)
>       176         embeddings = self.dropout(embeddings, training=training)
>       177         return embeddings
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       962         # Eager execution on data tensors.
>       963         with backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):
>   --> 964           self._maybe_build(inputs)
>       965           cast_inputs = self._maybe_cast_inputs(inputs)
>       966           with base_layer_utils.autocast_context_manager(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in _maybe_build(self, inputs)    2406           self._dtype_policy =
>   policy.Policy(dtype)    2407       input_shapes = None
>   -> 2408       if all(hasattr(x, 'shape') for x in input_list):    2409         input_shapes = nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.shape, inputs)    2410
>
> ## Only call `build` if the user has manually overridden the build method.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py
>   in (.0)    2406           self._dtype_policy =
>   policy.Policy(dtype)    2407       input_shapes = None
>   -> 2408       if all(hasattr(x, 'shape') for x in input_list):    2409         input_shapes = nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.shape, inputs)    2410
>
> ## Only call `build` if the user has manually overridden the build method.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
>   in shape(self)    1065         self._tensor_shape =
>   tensor_shape.TensorShape(self._shape_tuple())    1066       except
>   core._NotOkStatusException as e:
>   -> 1067         six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, e.message), None)    1068     1069     return self._tensor_shape
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value,
>   from_value)
>
> InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute AddV2 as input #1(zero-based) was
>   expected to be a bfloat16 tensor but is a float tensor

I suppose I have to cast something regarding the model ? How can I do that ? 
I am using tensorflow 2.1 and TPU v2.
I have see this thread but it was with tensorflow 1.X I suppose as the code does not work for me. 
[Memory reduction Tensorflow TPU v2/v3 bfloat16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458833/memory-reduction-tensorflow-tpu-v2-v3-bfloat16)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to load a pre-trained model trained with full floats into a b16float model. I don't think that will work. You have to train from scratch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is it not possible to convert the weights into bfloat16 ?